# Is it possible to play with wordpress content outside of wordpress with php files?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created two php files (recent_blog_post.php and single_blog_post.php) one for displaying post from wordpress site within same domain and another for displaying single post. I don’t know whether it is possible or not. The first one works fine but the problem is if i put the_permalink() in the title or read more link, the page redirects to main wordpress site. I don’t want to go back to main site, want linking to the custom php file to show each single post.  Here is my code for recent_blog_post.php

```
    <ul>
<?php 
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '../wordpress/wp-load.php'); 
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5
);
$latest_posts = new WP_Query( $args );  
if ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $latest_posts->have_posts() ) {
        $latest_posts->the_post(); ?>
<li>
     <h2><a href="single_blog_post.php/<?php I want post slug here ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <?php } 
    } else {
    echo '<p>There are no posts available</p>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</li>
</ul>
```

And single_blog_post.php

```
<?php   require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '../wordpress/wp-load.php'); 
query_posts('showposts=1');
 if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link:    <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>   

<?php the_content();?>
<?php edit_post_link('Edit', '<p>', '</p>'); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>  
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the filter "the_permalink"

```
function subs_url ( $url ) {
    return str_replace ( "www.mywebsite.com/", "www.mywebsite.com/single_blog_post.php/", $url );
}
add_filter('the_permalink', 'subs_url');
```

That filter will change your permalink from www.mywebsite.com/category/slug to www.mywebsite.com/single_blog_post.php/category/slug

Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_permalink